# Inject RDS secrets to Python in Lambda

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to transfer SQL Server RDS' secrets into my Python code that will be ran by Lambda.

What would be best approach to handle such transfer? Sholud it be done with `boto3` or/with AWS' Secrets Manager?

Sample Python code:

```
import pyodbc 

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=server_name;'
                          'Database=db_name;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db_name.Table')

    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Both. Store the secrets in Secrets Manager. Retrieve secrets from Secrets Manager using the boto3 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great walkthrough with code examples and more importantly, shows how to setup the exceptions in Python for boto3 and SecretsManager.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-securely-provide-database-credentials-to-lambda-functions-by-using-aws-secrets-manager/